# I cannot extract the body of the a tag using the web crawler in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

this is my code in python. I can extract the href tags just not whats inside the body. should I us "body" in with get() command or "content" or something else?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def web():
    url='https://www.phoenixmarketcity.com/mumbai/brands'
    source = requests.get(url)
    plain=source.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain,"html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        href = link.get('body')
        print(href)    

web()
```

Comment: `link.getText()`

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you want to do:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
def web():
    url='https://www.phoenixmarketcity.com/mumbai/brands'
    source = requests.get(url)
    plain=source.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain,"html.parser")
    tags = soup('a')
    for link in tags:
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)

    web()
```